# Tooltip for jmesa cells?

Tags: tooltip, jmesa

How can I add tooltips for all cells in one column for instance? I'm using a jmesa table.

I need this because in the cells i've got text like this: 'this is the ...'. On hover I need to display a tooltip with the complete text.

Answer (score 0):

Use a SPAN tag with a TITLE attribute to show the tooltip:

```
<jmesa:htmlColumn>
    <span title='${bean.fullDescription}'>${bean.value}</span>
</jmesa:htmlColumn>
```

Comment: i used this: http://www.queness.com/post/92/create-a-simple-cssjavascript-tooltip-with-jquery